# How do I use a custom widget (Network Image) in GButton (google_nav_bar)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using **google_nav_bar.dart** package for a BottomNavigationBar. I want to have a custom widget (Network Image) instead of an Icon. I tried a lot of things but nothing is working.

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar

My Code Snippet where I want to use NetworkImage.

```
GButton(
    icon: LineIcons.user,
    text: 'Profile',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `leading` property:

```
GButton(
  leading: SizedBox(
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    child: Image.network("http://via.placeholder.com/24x24"),
  ),
  text: 'Profile',
),
```

I'd recommend using `CachedNetworkImage`

https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

```
GButton(
  text: 'Search',
  leading: SizedBox(
    width: 24, 
    height: 24,
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/24x24",
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    ),
  ),
)
```